# WPF Mvvm move mouse button event to Command

Tags: c#, wpf, events, mvvm, command

I am starting to use MVVM but I'm finding difficult to replicate simple things that I do with events: I have a canvas and I want to get the position of the mouse click so I did a command and the xaml is this

```
<Canvas x:Name="cnvLeft">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseDown">
                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding CanvasClick}" 
                                    PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        
    </Canvas>
```

However it pass only the mouse arguments, which is not enough because i need the sender, how can i fix this?

Comment: Implementing MVVM does not mean that you are not allowed to use event handlers in the code behind of a view.

Comment: If you need a reference to the `Canvas`,  the code clearly belongs to the view or the control.

Comment: I needed to bind to a view model Command, my work around was to pass only the canvas as Command Parameter and then get the mouse position by the method Mouse.GetPosition, but as I said  I feel it's a work around and not the best way to do it

Comment: Just in case that has not become clear, determining the click position in a UI element is nothing that belongs into a view model. Do that in the view, and pass the result to your view model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As recommended already: register a common event handler for the mouse click event.

MVVM is not concerned with code-behind. It's absolutely fine and even necessary to use code-behind.
Code-behind files are a compiler feature i.e. language feature (partial classes). They have nothing to do with application architecture. MVVM does not care about compilers - no design pattern does.

MVVM is also not concerned with commands (or data binding or any framework concept in general). Commanding is part of the framework's infrastructure and MVVM does not care about frameworks - no design pattern does.
MVVM does not mean to use commands. Events are usually just as good. So don't force commands. Instead of using interaction behaviors to convert an input event to a command, simply handle the event directly (of course in the view).

Controls must *always* be handled in the View of an MVVM application. The code-behind file of a control is a partial class. It's part of the control and therefore part of the View.

Implement the user input event handler in the hosting control's code-behind. Here you must implement the `Canvas` related logic (UI logic).
If you want to encapsulate the logic, you can move it along with the `Canvas` to a new custom `Control` (or `UserControl`).

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <Canvas PreviewMouseDown="OnCanvasePreviewMouseDown" />
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
private void OnCanvasePreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  var canvas = sender as Canvas;
  Point canvasClickPosition = e.GetPosition(canvas);
}
```

Comment: Great rebuttal to the MVVM "purists".